# Flex - Yacc: undefined reference to `YY_CURRENT_BUFFER'

Tags: c, flex-lexer, yacc

I am making a compiler using Flex-Yacc and I am currently trying to make a buffer system to help me implement the for and while loops. I have read the Flex manual
([here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex/html_node/flex_12.html)) and when I use the YY_CURRENT_BUFFER in my yacc file and I compile it, I get 
    `undefined reference to YY_CURRENT_BUFFER`. How can I declare/include this in my code? I have searched a lot but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: How would this help you with implementing loops?

Comment: @sepp2k I want to read the file, spot the loop code, get it in a string and then make a buffer out of it and execute it again and again while the condition is true.

Comment: So you're saying that, while parsing the loop for the first time, you want to produce a string containing the parsed loop's source code, and then you want to feed that string back into the lexer and re-tokenize and re-parse the code for each iteration of the loop? How would that work with nested loops? Even if you can get that approach to work, it seems pretty complicated to me and not how flex and yacc are meant to be used. I'd strongly suggest just generating some form of AST or IR in the parser instead.

Comment: What is an IR ?

Comment: Sorry, it's short for "intermediate representation", such as some form of bytecode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"YY_CURRENT_BUFFER" is not a variable, but a macro local to the lexer (it's not exported in the header generated by `lex --header-file`, and it expands to an expression using static variables (ie variables that are local to lex.yy.c, not global, not accessible from other source files).

You should wrap all the code making use of "YY_CURRENT_BUFFER" in a function in the lexer (*.l) file, put its definition in a header included in the parser (*.y) file, and use that function instead of "YY_CURRENT_BUFFER" directly.